# How to control two elements separately for toggling states to true and false

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

How to control two elements separately for toggling states to `true` and `false`.Is there a way to simplify this code? Writing different states and functions for every component seems to be the wrong approach. And what if there would be more than two components?

```
 const [active, setActiveItem] = React.useState(false);
    const [active2, setActiveItem2] = React.useState(false);
        
      function toggle() {
        setActive((active) => !active);
      }
    
      function toggle2() {
            setActiveItem2((active) => !active);
        }
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <CustomButton onPress={toggle} active={active} />
          <CustomButton onPress={toggle2} active={active2} />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps so:

```js
const [actives, setActives] = React.useState({
  active1: false,
  active2: false,
  active3: false,
  active4: false,
});

const toggle = (key) => setActives((actives) => ({ ...actives, [key]: !actives[key] }));
    
return (
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <CustomButton onPress={() => toggle('active1')} active={actives.active1} />
    <CustomButton onPress={() => toggle('active2')} active={actives.active2} />
    <CustomButton onPress={() => toggle('active3')} active={actives.active3} />
    <CustomButton onPress={() => toggle('active4')} active={actives.active4} />
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do something like this

```
const [active, setActiveItem] = React.useState(false);
    const [active2, setActiveItem2] = React.useState(false);

        
      function toggle(setFunction) {
        setFunction((someState) => !someState);
      }
    
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <CustomButton onPress={()=>toggle(setActiveItem)} active={active} />
          <CustomButton onPress={()=>toggle(setActiveItem2)} active={active2} />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What would be the TypeScript types for setFunction and someState?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash map for keeping state, instead of boolean

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  0: false,
  1: true,
  2: false
});

return (
  Object.keys(state).map((id) => <CustomButton 
    key={id} 
    onPress={() => {setState(prev => ({...prev, [id]: !prev[id]}))}} 
    active={state[id]} 
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE SOLUTION | using just a **single** state variable,

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState(true);
    
  function toggle() {
    setActive(!active);
  }
   
  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
    { active ?
    <CustomButton onPress={toggle} active={active} />
    : <CustomButton onPress={toggle} active={!active} />
    }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `useToggle` custom hook and use it twice:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const useToggle = (initial = false) => {
 const [active, setActive] = useState(initial);
       
  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    setActive(prev => !prev);
  }, []);
    
  return [active, toggle];
}

const Demo = () => {
  const [active1, toggle1] = useToggle();
  const [active2, toggle2] = useToggle(true);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle1}>Toggle 1 - {active1 ? 'on' : 'off'}</button>
      <button onClick={toggle2}>Toggle 2 - {active2 ? 'on' : 'off'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```